# config.xml and ripple/user-agent not found when using ionic and ngCordova with ripple simulator

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ripple, ngcordova

is that normal ? and if no how should I fix it ?

Copy / Past from chrome console since I can't yet post images :

```
Console was cleared
ripple.js:37 Ripple :: Environment Warming Up (Tea. Earl Gray. Hot.)
ripple.js:50 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
ripple.js:50 GET http://localhost/csDown/www/config.xml 404 (Not Found)
ripple.js:50 POST http://localhost/csDown/www/ripple/user-agent 404 (Not Found)
ripple.js:37 cordova :: Setting the user agent server side failed.
ripple.js:37 cordova :: Initialization Finished (Make it so.)
ripple.js:40 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fire' of undefined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's running fine my friend. You can't find `config.xml` if you run inside the emulator, you need to run it inside actual device.

Comment: Thanks a lot am new in this kind of dev so it's not that obvious for me.